# Order management including recurring orders on woocommerce

Tags: order, management

I've been trying to find a good way for handling order management as I have some recurring payments on my business. I need to set up a system that informs me how many items I should have in stock every week based on the recurring orders and the average of the daily orders that I receive from online and telephone. I really appreciate if someone helps me on this. also, is it ok to keep everything on Wordpress or I should use a third party application for these tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WooCommerce?  Are you using an additional plugin for recurring orders?  I am asking because I have a site setup using [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/).

It works nicely and I am able to generate reports in the admin.  WooCommerce > Reports.  There are several Woo default reports I can run but the subscription plugin adds some more, one of them being "Upcoming Recurring Revenue" which sounds like what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I also use the Woocommerce subscription for recurring orders. The problem I have is how to forecast the inventory once we have both daily orders and recurring orders to fulfill. That is the issue we have now to see how to solve in Woocommerece.

Comment: The "Upcoming Recurring Revenue" report isn't useful to you?  You can review a report for the next week/month/year.

Comment: Actually that looks very interesting. thanks for the suggestion. I get some orders by phone other than online, I guess it will also count them once I import them into woocommerce.